# Ngrx App using ngrx latest version always undefined store object

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I have a Simple App

**Without NGRX**

**Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-competition',
  templateUrl: './component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component.css']
})
export class Component implements OnInit {

constructor(private Service:Service){}

    comp:any[];

    ngOnInit(){this.Service.get().subscribe(comp => this.comp)}
```

**Service**

```
@Injectable()

export class CompetitionService{


  constructor(private http:Http, private af: AngularFireDatabase){

  }

  getComp(){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('X-Auth-Token', 'XXXXX');
    return this.http.get('URL',{headers:headers}).map(response => response.json())
  }
```

All these works Fine when i try to convert it to ngrx it dosent work using store and effects.

**USING NGRX**

Created a STATE in component

```
export interface AppState{
    comp:any;
}

ngOnInit(){
        this.store.dispatch({type:GET_COMP,payload: {}});
}
```

**ACTIONS**

```
export const GET_COMP = 'GET_COMP';
export const SUCCESS = 'SUCCESS';

export class GetAction implements Action {
  readonly type = GET_COMP;

  constructor(public payload: any) {}
}

export class SuccessAction implements Action {
  readonly type = SUCCESS;

  constructor(public payload: any) {}
}

export type Actions =
  | GetAction
  | SuccessAction
;
```

**EFFECTS**

```
@Injectable()
export class MainEffects {

  constructor(private action$: Actions, private service$ :CompetitionService ) { }

  @Effect() load$:Observable<Action> = this.action$
      // Listen for the 'LOGIN' action
      .ofType(GET_COMP)
      .switchMap(action => this.service$.getComp()
        // If successful, dispatch success action with result
        .map(res => ({ type: SUCCESS, payload: res}))
        // If request fails, dispatch failed action
        .catch((err) => Observable.of({ type: 'FAILED' ,payload :err}))  
      );
}
```

**REDUCER**

```
export function MainReducer(state = [],action: GetAction) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_COMP:
            return [action.payload];
        default:
            return state;
  }
}
```

**APP.MODULE**

```
StoreModule.forRoot({MainReducer}),
EffectsModule.forRoot([MainEffects])
```

It goes to the Service call i did a log but while getting it in component i get the following

[image]

Sorry for the long post just wanted to keep you informed.

I Followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQi5cDA0Kj8 
and also this https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/48a2381c212d5dd3fa2b9435776c1aaa60734235/example-app/app/books/reducers/books.ts

Comment: Read this [**medium post**](https://medium.com/@aravindfz/setting-up-storemodule-in-ngrx-4-0-b7c60732aa64)

Comment: @Aravind Same thing aravind i registered the reducer that was missing in Action Reducer Map but no effect .
I get the same Store scalr properties in console where is the object . that i get from database ? that causes my ngfor to throw error saying its only for array not for object object

Comment: The only thing different in my case is i dont have a model i use any in comp , how to use this with `any` type ? please help

Comment: where are you using `any` type?

Comment: If you see the appstate it has a property of `comp:any`

Comment: Any idea whats could be.missing

Answer (score 1):

I as per my experience have created a pseudo code, as to how your code should look like below.

- `GetAction` should have no payload. As you are calling it to just fire the web service which does not takes any input.
- You should add `error` in your `state` to keep tracks of errors.
- You should use `selectors` to get the value of the state
- You should subscribe to the `store` and then assign the values.

**STATE**

```
export interface FeatureState {
  comp: any;
  error: any;
}

export interface AppState {
  feature: FeatureState
}
```

**ACTIONS**

```
export const GET_COMP = 'GET_COMP';
export const SUCCESS = 'SUCCESS';
export const FAILED = 'FAILED';


export class GetAction implements Action {
  readonly type = GET_COMP;
}

export class SuccessAction implements Action {
  readonly type = SUCCESS;

  constructor(public payload: any) {}
}

export class FailedAction implements Action {
  readonly type = FAILED;

  constructor(public payload: any) {}
}

export type Actions =
  | GetAction
  | SuccessAction
;
```

**REDUCER**

```
export function MainReducer(state = [],action: GetAction) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                comp: action.payload
            };
    case FAILED:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;

}
```

**SELECTORS**

```
import { createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';

export const selectFeature = (state: AppState) => state.feature;
export const selectFeatureCount = createSelector(selectFeature, (state: FeatureState) => state.count);
```

**COMPONENT**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-competition',
  templateUrl: './component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component.css']
})
export class Component implements OnInit {

constructor(private action: OurAction , private store: Store){}

    comp:any[];

    ngOnInit(){
        this.store.dispatch(new OurAction.GetAction());
        this.store.select(selectFeature).subscribe(state => {
          this.comp = state.comp;
        });
    }
```

**App.module.ts**

```
StoreModule.forRoot({ feature : MainReducer }),
EffectsModule.forRoot([MainEffects])
```

Comment: i am getting a error from IDE  Type '"SUCCESS"' is not comparable to type '"GET_COMP"'.

Comment: in reducer you have defined GETAction where as success dosent have get action

Comment: And what is state.counter in `selectors` and why do we need to use selectors ?

Comment: Also `store<T>` has to have a generic type of T and we cannot select the `selectFeatureComp` it telling not a property of store

Comment: I am totally confused @Anurag

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake, instead of `counter` it should be `comp`

Comment: The general idea behind this is, When you dispatch an action of using `action. GetAction `, your effect will intercept it, which will fire the service `this.service$.getComp`, which does not have any data required from action, so you don't have to pass any payload. Then your effect will fire `SUCCESS` with `response` as payload. Your reducer will update your store with this payload for `SUCESS` action.

Comment: Once your store is update, your component need to know that the value has been updated in the store. This is where your `selector` kicks in. Selectors are easy way out to get data from your store, generally useful if your store consists of lot of state variables. As you are subscribing in your component for the `selectFeature`, your data in component will get updated once your store get's updated

Comment: If you want to see a working example, I have this code on my github repo - https://github.com/anuragsinghbisht/Angular2_FrontEnd

Comment: instead of this line `this.store.dispatch(new OurAction.GetAction());` cant we have something like this `this.store.dispatch({type : GET_COMP});`

Comment: also i feel that this line `export function MainReducer(state = [],action: GetAction) {` is incorrect it should be `export function MainReducer(state = [],action: Actions) {` as it throws error in my code

Comment: also can you check this line `constructor(private action: OurAction , private store: Store){}` should be `private store: Store<AppState>` or feature state confusing

Comment: what ever i do i get this error any fix man `CompetitionComponent_Host.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'comp' of undefined` it goes to service i have logged it there but dnt knw what happens

Comment: `this.store.dispatch(new OurAction.GetAction())` is used in `ngrx` documentation for calling actions created using `class`. So I am not sure if other way will work

Comment: `export function MainReducer(state = [],action: Actions) {` yes this should be the code. I copied it from your code only.. I have just added the `SUCCESS` and `FAILED` in the reducer

Comment: `private store: Store<AppState>` yes it should be this.

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'comp' of undefined` you might be getting this because there is some problem in the `state` you have defined. Mine is just a pseudo code. It's not accurate.. you can check my github repo for the working code.